# How to use Java Spring MongoOperations to execute mongodb collection methods?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to calculate the size of the collection for my database. MongoDB has this collection method `db.collection.totalsize()`. I am having trouble finding how to write the method with the MongoOperations provided by spring.

I am currently trying to use a `Basic Query` to run the raw query but it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post any code?

Comment: This is what I have tried ```MongoOperations mongoOperations; this.mongoOperations.findOne(new BasicQuery("db."+collectionName+".totalSize()"), Long.class)```

Comment: Can you show how you use the `MongoTemplate` class? Do you have a `MongoRepository` set up?

Comment: No. The operations are done on MongoOperations The codebase has an implementation of a repository interface. Sorry, I need to reframe the question.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error is thrown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236862/discussion-between-shix-and-fermi-4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoOperations is not working here because `db.collection.totalSize()` is a [mongo shell command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.totalSize/), not a query

Instead of calling `findOne` you can call `executeCommand()`

```
private final BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
basicDBObject.put("eval", "function() { return db.collection.totalSize(); }");
CommandResult result = mongoOperations.executeCommand(basicDBObject);
```

Another way to do this is through an instance of `MongoDatabase`

If you can access an instance of `MongoClient` you can then get a reference to `MongoDatabase`

Once you have an instance of `MongoDatabase` you need to call `MongoDatabase.runCommand()` and pass in your shell command ('db.collection.totalSize()') as a `Bson` object and then get your result.

Basically you need to do something like this:

```
String uri = "mongo uri string"
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri)
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("your database");
String commandStr = "db.collection.totalSize()"; // or custom collection name in your case
Bson command = new BsonDocument(commandStr, new BsonInt64(1));
Document commandResult = database.runCommand(command);
```

In spring, you might be able to `@Autowire` an instance of one of `MongoClient` or `MongoDatabase` in already - check the bean configuration and autoconfiguration in your project.